# Mysql Getting Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) constantly in log

Tags: mysql, logins

I have MonYog running and it is monitoring my DB Server. It gives me constant alerts that the number of refused connections has exceeded the threshold etc. Looking in the LySQL.Log I can see constant login failures for root@localhost.

This is on a hosted server out in the ether so I have been as strict as possible with access etc. Firstly, the 3306 port on the firewall is open only to a couple of selected IP addresses. All other users (for dev and testing etc) use SSH. Secondly, there is no 'root' user. I renamed the root account to something else. This new named account only has localhost access.

So from the above, I just don't see how any login attempts are getting to the DB from localhost. The 3306 port is closed to all but one IP address (mine) and I am not attempting any connect to the server all through the night as the logs are showing. And anyway, I never connect as the (new) root dba user unless I need to do some special admin task.

Is there any way of finding out where these login attempts are coming from (IP address, host name, application name etc...).

Or am I looking in the wrong place. I just cant work out where they are coming from but I am convinced it cant be good!

Comment: "constant alerts that the number of refused connections has exceeded the threshold etc." -- what?  Please don't paraphrase... what exactly do these alerts say?

Answer (score 1):

A) You can check TCPdump output for MySQL port connection.

B) Also you can verify whether any script is running on MySQL server may be something like `monit` etc.. which continuously pings MySQL port.

Comment: Hi Mahesh. Thanks for the ideas. Ran Wireshark on the server. The Access denied messages are appearing with no network traffic at al so must be coming from local machine. I just cant work out where. You mention scripts running on the server. How do I find such things?

Comment: I have myself got in this situation and we found out that monit script was a problem, you can check if any script is running which does activity on MySQL server .. check for monit, backup script etc..

Comment: Thanks again. My server is a Windows server. Assume Monit is a linux thing? So how do I find any scripts set to run on my DB. I am not aware of setting any up but they may be there. I just dont know where to look to see if there are any.

Comment: Ok .. you can check for any scheduled job running for a MySQL server .. like you might have started backup job which is not connecting or some store procedure calls etc ..